# Xcode configuration and CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, configuration, xcode6, project, cocoapods

Is there any way to not overwrite custom project configurations by auto installing Cocoapods (Pods.debug.xcconfig and Pods.release.xcconfig).
I would like to use my own custom configs and just #include mentioned above Pods configs.

At this moment I'm using `pod install --no-integrate` command, I wonder is there any better solution?

Don't like this approach because firstly have to build `pod install` to create in Pods project custom configurations then switch my configurations on own in My Project then I can use --no-integrate option.

I wonder how to optimise this process.